# Проброс исключения в методе интерфейса

Tags: java, исключения

Зачем указывать для не дефолтного и не статического (т.е. обычного) метода интерфейса пробрасываемое им исключение?

Ведь при реализации данного метода в каком-то классе, имплементирующем данный интерфейс мы вовсе не обязаны обеспечить проброс данного исключения.

Вот пример:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public interface MyCommand {
    void exit() throws IOException;
}

public class Main implements MyCommand{
    @Override
    public void exit() {
        System.out.println("Сработал метод exit()");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: интерфейс он не для Вас, он для вызывающей стороны и он показывает что вызывающая сторона должна  обработать исключение, а бросите вы его или нет в конкретной реализации уже дело реализации

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Но, почему в примере я (вызывающая сторона в методе main) создаю объект класса, реализующего вышеуказанный интерфейс и вызываю его метод, который как я знаю, должен (согласно описанию) пробрасывать исключение, однако, он почему-то не требует его обработки. Или он и не должен требовать и обработка тоже лишь на моё усмотрение?

Comment: @ИванСапронов не забудьте принять ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интерфейс он не для Вас, он для вызывающей стороны и он показывает что вызывающая сторона должна обработать исключение, а бросите вы его или нет в конкретной реализации уже дело реализации.

---

В вашем примере при вызове исключение не требуется к обработке т.к. вы обращаетесь не к интерфейсу, а к объекту `Main` и его методу `exit` напрямую, приведите тип и все произойдет, вот полюбуйтесь:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public interface MyCommand {
    void exit() throws IOException;
}

public class Main implements MyCommand{
    @Override
    public void exit() {
        System.out.println("Сработал метод exit()");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        // не требует обработки т.к. метод Main.exit не имеет исключения в сигнатуре
        m.exit();

        MyCommand c = (MyCommand) m;
        // требует обработки т.к. метод MyCommand.exit имеет исключение в сигнатуре
        c.exit();
    }
}
```